# Class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I am using Fragment for the designing of the Firebase simple login registration.

I get error in the `OnCreateView()` method on initializing

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

error:- Error:(58, 28) error: cannot access zzaja
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja not found
please help
source:- http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 61):

I solved this exact problem today and stumbled onto this unanswered question by chance during the process.

First, ensure you've properly setup Firebase for Android as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup. Then, make sure you are compiling the latest version of the Firebase APIs (9.2.0) and the Google Play Services APIs (9.2.0) that you are using. My gradle dependencies look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also worth noting that if you use the open source FirebaseUI library then use dependencies from there for all components of Firebase platform OR make sure your FirebaseUI library use internal the same version as your other Firebase components.
TD;DR
**bad**:
`compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'`
**good**:
`compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
'compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'` 
OR
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'`

Comment: fixed after updating to 10.0.1

Answer (score 20):

I had such a similar error when i was recently upgrading my play service dependency. **It seems to occur when you leave out updating the firebase dependencies** that correspond to the version of play services you use. I beleive this is the most recent update of these dependencies

Here is what the two versions of my dependencies were:

Error version of dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
```

Working version of dependencies
``

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'
```

``
Google seems to move play service updates along with firebase updates these days. Hopes this saves a few souls out there.

Answer (score 17):

If you use different version of play services libraries, you will get this error.

For example, below entries in build.gradle file cause the error as versions are different.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

To fix the issue use same versions.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 8):

All your firebase version should be with same Version whatever it

like this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, the short answer is: **update your library version**. Android studio will tell you that there is a new version of it with a message like:

> A newer version of com.google.firebase:firebase-core than 14.0.4 is
>   available: 16.0.4

Just **move to that line**, press **Alt + Enter** and select **Change to X.X** where X.X is the newer version.

This way, you can update all your libraries. **Repeat the process** with all the libraries and you are done.

Comment: This is very nice idea "press Alt + Enter and select Change to X.X" 
its easy to change version other wise first do google then change it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using more than one libraries of firebase then make sure that the version are same.

```
Before:
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'

After:  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

in my case i have used auth with 9.0.2 .So i changed to 9.2.0

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem in june of 2017 changing the play-services versions for the latest firebase versions (9.6.1). When I used the latest play-services version (10.2.4) I got that error. The code in the gradle looks like this:

*Before*

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
```

*After*

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

play services, firebase, gradle plugin latest version combination that worked for me.
try app module build.gradle

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "my package name"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            publishNonDefault true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        } }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project level build.gradle like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a also same problem.Change old version of FirebaseAuth to newer version. for me I change `"com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0"` to `"com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"`

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), Add the latest version of the Google Service plugin (4.0.1 on 06/04/18). Hope this hepls!

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not mix 12 and 15, use this

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem occurred with me. By updating library to latest one will resolve this problem.

After updating don't forget to do Sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem by getting the **latest version** of the Firebase Libraries for Android SDK.

You can get the latest library from https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

**Example:**

**Before:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.6.0'
```

to

**After:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure all the implementations of firebase you are using have the same version inside the dependencies in build.gradle (app).

Answer (score 1):

Just Simply Add this two dependency to your pubspec.yml. this works for me.

---

firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1
firebase_core: ^0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs only due to the difference in version. Whenever this kinda error occurs try to change the SDK versions, Gradle Build versions, or dependency version.
If you are using

```
targetSdkVersion = 26
compileSdkVersion = 26
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

then add this version for firebase dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
```

It works.

Comment: Is there any way what right match of versions for all these libraries?