# Error:(53, 29) error: cannot access zzbti class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbti not found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I' trying out firebase for user authentication. I had followed the instruction under Android Studio Firebase but I'm getting this error ->

```
Error:(53, 29) error: cannot access zzbti
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbti not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073706/class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzaja-not-found)

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon the same error, checking the Firebase documentation I realised my dependencies in my build.gradle(Module.App) were not up-to-date, so I changed them so that they match the ones in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup then I synced and the error disappeared.