# Cannot access zzbgl

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

So i tried adding ads on my app. It looks like i did it well but for some  reason i get this Error : error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found. Once i click on this error it takes me to the mapactivity that i made. It doesn't show specific problem there too. I tried changing play-services-location and play-services-maps version from 12.0.0 to 16.0.0. It seemed that it worked but once i start my app it crashes. Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be gladly apreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073706/class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzaja-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradle settings: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694569/gradle-settings-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzbgl-not-found)